# How to find all variables with identical id?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy

Let's say I have a `numpy` array `a` and create `b` like this:

```
a = np.arange(3)
b = a
```

If I now change `b` e.g. like this

```
b[0] = 100
```

and print `a`, `b`, their `id`s and `.flags`

```
print a
print a.flags    
print b
print b.flags
print id(a)
print id(b)
```

I obtain

```
[100   1   2]

  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

[100   1   2]

  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

139767698376944
139767698376944
```

So, `a` and `b` look the same and their `id`s are identical as expected.

When I now do the same using `copy()`

```
c = np.arange(3)
d = c.copy()

d[0] = 20

print c
print c.flags
print id(c)

print d
print d.flags
print id(d)
```

I get

```
[0 1 2]

  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

139767698377344

[20  1  2]

  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

139767698376864
```

In this case `c` and `d` differ and so do their `id`s; also as expected.

However, what confuses me is the output I obtain from `.flags`: In all cases, `OWNDATA` is set to `True`. When I read the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html), I find:

> OWNDATA (O)   The array owns the memory it uses or borrows it from
>   another object.

My main question is now:

What would be the easiest way to find all variables that point to the same `id` (in the example above `a` and `b`) i.e. to check whether another variable with the same id exists? I thought `OWNDATA` would be of help for that but apparently it is not.

Related question:

What is `OWNDATA` actually used for, in which case is `OWNDATA` set to `False`?

Comment: You seem to be unclear about what `=` does in Python. When you do `b = a`, you don't have two arrays. [Here's a quick guide to what `=` means in this language.](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but the question would remain: How to find all variables with identical ids? And what is OWNDATA actually used for?

Comment: There is only ever one object at a time with a given ID.

Comment: Ok, then how to find all variables that have the same id?

Comment: IDs are unique to each object; there are no two objects with identical IDs. Perhaps you mean references to an object, but it's impractical to get a full list of them, and there's no good reason to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues - how do you identify the variables that you want to compare, and how to do you compare them.

Take the second first.

My version (1.8.2) does not have a `np.shares_memory` function.  It does have a `np.may_share_memory`.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6166 is the pull request that adds `shares_memory`; it' dated last August.  So you'd have to have brand new `numpy` to use it.  Note that a definitive test is potentially hard, and it may issue as 'TOO HARD' error message.  I imagine, for example that there are some slices that share the memory, but hard to identify by simply comparing buffer starting points.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/core/tests/test_mem_overlap.py is the unit test for these `memory_overlap` functions.  Read it if you want to see what a daunting task it is to think of all the possible overlap conditions between 2 known arrays.

I like to look at the array's `.__array_interface__`.  One item in that dictionary is 'data', which is a pointer to the data buffer.  Identical pointer means the data is shared.  But a view might start somewhere down the line.  I wouldn't be surprised if `shares_memeory` looks at this pointer.

Identical `id` means 2 variables reference the same object, but different array objects can share a data buffer.

All these tests require looking specific references; so you still need to get some sort of list of references.  Look at `locals()`?, `globals()`.  What about unnamed references, such as list of arrays, or some user defined dictionary?

An example Ipython run:

Some variables and references:

```
In [1]: a=np.arange(10)
In [2]: b=a           # reference
In [3]: c=a[:]        # view
In [4]: d=a.copy()    # copy
In [5]: e=a[2:]       # another view
In [6]: ll=[a, a[:], a[3:], a[[1,2,3]]]  # list
```

Compare `id`:

```
In [7]: id(a)
Out[7]: 142453472
In [9]: id(b)
Out[9]: 142453472
```

None of the others share the `id`, except `ll[0]`.

```
In [10]: np.may_share_memory(a,b)
Out[10]: True
In [11]: np.may_share_memory(a,c)
Out[11]: True
In [12]: np.may_share_memory(a,d)
Out[12]: False
In [13]: np.may_share_memory(a,e)
Out[13]: True
In [14]: np.may_share_memory(a,ll[3])
Out[14]: False
```

That's about what I'd expect; views share memory, copies do not.

```
In [15]: a.__array_interface__
Out[15]: 
{'version': 3,
 'data': (143173312, False),
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (10,),
 'strides': None}
In [16]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[16]: (143173312, False)
In [17]: b.__array_interface__['data']
Out[17]: (143173312, False)
In [18]: c.__array_interface__['data']
Out[18]: (143173312, False)
In [19]: d.__array_interface__['data']
Out[19]: (151258096, False)            # copy - diff buffer
In [20]: e.__array_interface__['data'] 
Out[20]: (143173320, False)            # differs by 8 bytes
In [21]: ll[1].__array_interface__['data']
Out[21]: (143173312, False)            # same point
```

Just with this short session I hav 76 items in `locals()`.  But I can search it for matching `id` with:

```
In [26]: [(k,v) for k,v in locals().items() if id(v)==id(a)]
Out[26]: 
[('a', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])),
 ('b', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))]
```

Same for the other tests.

I can search `ll` in the same way:

```
In [28]: [n for n,l in enumerate(ll) if id(l)==id(a)]
Out[28]: [0]
```

And I could add a layer to the `locals()` search by testing if an item is a list or dictionary, and doing a search within that.

So even if we settle on the testing method, it isn't trivial to search for all possible references.

I think the best approach is to just understand your own use of variables, so that you can clearly identify references, views and copies.  In selected cases you can perform tests like `may_share_memory` or comparing databuffers.  But there isn't an inexpensive, definitive test.  When in doubt it is cheaper to make a copy, than to risk over writing something.  In my years of `numpy` use I've never felt the need to an definitive answer to this question.

---

I don't find the `OWNDATA` flag very useful.  Consider the above variables

```
In [35]: a.flags['OWNDATA']
Out[35]: True
In [36]: b.flags['OWNDATA']   # ref
Out[36]: True
In [37]: c.flags['OWNDATA']   # view
Out[37]: False
In [38]: d.flags['OWNDATA']   # copy
Out[38]: True
In [39]: e.flags['OWNDATA']   # view
Out[39]: False
```

While I can predict the `OWNDATA` value in these simple cases, its value doesn't say much about shared memory, or shared id.  `False` suggests it was created from another array, and thus may share memory.  But that's just a 'may'.

I often create a sample array by reshaping a range.

```
In [40]: np.arange(3).flags['OWNDATA']
Out[40]: True
In [41]: np.arange(4).reshape(2,2).flags['OWNDATA']
Out[41]: False
```

There's clearly no other reference to the data, but the reshaped array does not 'own' its own data.  Same would happen with

```
temp = np.arange(4); temp = temp.reshape(2,2)
```

I'd have to do

```
temp = np.arange(4); temp.shape = (2,2)
```

to keep `OWNDATA` true. False `OWNDATA` means something right after creating the new array object, but it doesn't change if the original reference is redefined or deleted.  It easily becomes out of date.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed reply, I go through it later today.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question, therefore I upvote and also accept it. In general you are correct: one should know the own variables but I just had to use another person's code and unfortunately, this person did not no about copy(). Now I really want to make sure to filter out all possible problems that might be caused by that. But I have to admit that my question was not particular clear; now I would ask in another way...

Answer (score 4):

The assignment `b=a` does not create a view on the original array `a` but simply creates a reference to it. In other words, `b` is just a different name for `a`. Both variables `a` and `b` refer to the *same* array which owns its data such that the `OWNDATA` flag is set. Modifying `b` will modify `a`.

The assignment `b=a.copy()` creates a copy of the original array. That is, `a` and `b` refer to separate arrays which both own their data such that the `OWNDATA` flag is set. Modifying `b` will not modify `a`.

However, if you make the assignment `b=a[:]`, you will create a view of the original array and `b` will not own its data. Modifying `b` will modify `a`.

The [`shares_memory`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html#numpy.shares_memory) function is what you are looking for. It does what it says on the box: Check whether to arrays `a` and `b` have shared memory and thus affect each other.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that is kind of clear (apart from the OWNDATA part). That's why I gave these examples and wrote that I get the expected outcome. Question is more whether I can get a function that returns True if a change would affect another variable and False if it does not. So in this case: func(b) = True, func (d) = False

Comment: Updated to address your specific question.

Comment: Thanks, this function indeed looks what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! I upvote your answer and might accept it later on depending on the quality of other answers!

Comment: @Cleb, You are giving confliciting signals.  You objected to another answer because it ' requires that I already know which variables I want to check'.  Doesn't `shares_memory` require the same?  Plus `shares_memory` doesn't check ids, which what your title specifies.

Comment: @hpaulj: Your are totally right; I was indeed inconsistent in my comments - I realize that now, yesterday I was apparently too tired. Unfortunately, the other user already deleted his/her answer.