# numpy: Reliable (non-conservative) indicator if numpy array is view

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

Looking for a way to reliably identify if a numpy object is a view.

Related questions have come up many times before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286864/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-numpy-arrays-share-the-same-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747748/how-do-i-check-that-two-slices-of-numpy-arrays-are-the-same-or-overlapping), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886731/numpy-reshape-on-view)), and people have offered some solutions, but all seem to have problems:

- The test used in `pandas` now is to call something a view if `my_array.base is not None`. This seems to always catch views, but also offers lots of false positives (situations where it reports something is a view even if it isn't).
- `numpy.may_share_memory()` will check for two specific arrays, but won't answer generically

  - (@RobertKurn says was best tool as of 2012 -- any changes?)
- `flags['OWNDATA'])` is [reported (third comment first answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524664/how-can-i-tell-if-numpy-creates-a-view-or-a-copy) to fail in some cases.

(The reason for my interest is that I'm working on implementing copy-on-write for pandas, and a conservative indicator is leading to over-copying.)

Comment: relevant discussion on the numpy github tracker: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5604

Comment: The situations described as false positives seem to be when an operation that "creates a copy" actually returns a view of a copy. If this is to be considered "not a view", you might try checking the refcount of the array's `base` to see whether there are any other references to it, but that won't be perfect. I don't think it's possible to reliably detect this kind of thing.

Comment: Also see this recent SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467477/how-to-find-all-variables-with-identical-id.  It mentions a new function, `np.shares_memory`.  But I streesed there that it's one thing to compare 2 known variables, quite another to ask is an array shares the data buffer with any other array.

Comment: How about an numpy array a view onto which is created later, how do you want to treat that original array?

Comment: For my purposes, original is ok to treat as "not a view".

Comment: My five cents: it is pointless to have a view with offset zero, default strides and a size computed from shape and itemsize that's equal to the size of the buffer. So anything having zero offset, default strides and a shape that matches the buffer is probably no view. Default strides given by: 
   strides = [itemsize];
   for dim in reversed (shape [1 : ]):
    strides.insert (0, strides [0] * dim)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your usages, `flags['OWNDATA']` would do the job. 
In fact, there's no problem with your link. **It does not fail in some cases**. It will always do what it's supposed to do.

According to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.require.html: the flag "ensure an array that owns its own data".

In your "counterexample", they use the code:

```
print (b.flags['OWNDATA'])  #False -- apparently this is a view
e = np.ravel(b[:, 2])
print (e.flags['OWNDATA'])  #True -- Apparently this is a new numpy object.
```

But, it's the normal behaviour to be True in the second case.

It comes from the definition of `ravel` (from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).

> Return a contiguous flattened array.
>   A 1-D array, containing the elements of the input, is returned. A copy is made only if needed.

Here, a copy is needed, so a copy is made. So, the variable e really owns its own data. It's not a "view of b", "a reference to b", "an alias to a part of b". It's a real new array that contains a copy of some elements of b.

So, **I think that it's impossible without tracking the entire origin of the data to detect that kind of behaviour**. I believe you should be able to build your program with that flag.